# How to move first element of object to first Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, object

My object is something like this

```
object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection)[8565]
protected '_items' => 
 array (size=3)
  15841610 => 
    object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)[8701]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=28)
          ...
  15841611 => 
    object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)[8750]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=28)
          ...
  15841612 => 
    object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)[8563]
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=28)
```

whats that '_items' string, how can I move the last element with `key` = 15841612 to the first and shift others.

I have tried this with an array but for the object, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a collection model with _items property which holds all collection's items as array (and each element in array will be instance of Magento\Framework\DataObject class). You can't move it inside the collection and then use collection with new order of items there (if you need that way, you can use conditions in prepared select), but instead you can get items from collection (once again, here you will have an array) and do manipulations as with array in PHP, so to do it (in case, if you want to move LAST element to the beginning on the items array):

```
$items = $yourCollection->getItems();
$lastItem = array_pop($items);
array_unshift($items, $lastItem);
```